# calling function from normal mode without *noremap

Tags: key-bindings, functions

I realise this might be impossible, but thought it might be worth asking anyway.
In vim, the typical way I map keys to functions is using `*noremap` commands. However the downside of this is the fact that the mapping is not a call to the function. Instead, it automatically literally types out the characters needed to invoke said function; getting a command prompt with `:`, typing `call` and the function name, hitting return, etc. Is there a way I can bind a key to a function directly without this intermediary step, much like how `hjkl` immediately invoke internal functions that actually do the work of changing the cursor position? Or is this kind of functionality not exposed to the user by vim?

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, the answer is no, `:call` *is* the mechanism for invoking functions starting from normal mode, but there are at least two mechanisms I can think of that you could theoretically use if you needed to call a function from a normal-mode mapping but the colon key had been stolen from your keyboard:

## Expression mappings

Expression mappings work by evaluating an expression and then mapping to the result. A function call is a valid expression, thus:

```
nnoremap <expr> <f2> Function()
```

However, there are several limitations to what you can actually do *during* that function: e.g. you can move the cursor but it will be moved back afterwards. See `:help map-expr` for the full set of limitations and other details.

## The expression register

Vim has a register called the “expression register” which you can use to evaluate expressions in certain circumstances. This *could* be used to run a function from a normal mode mapping by e.g. entering insert mode first:

```
nnoremap <f2> i<C-R>=Function()<CR><Esc>
```

In case it’s not already clear, this would be an asinine thing to do, but the expression register *is* very useful in other contexts. See `:help "=` for more details.